# Replace double quoted strings by single quoted except for GStrings

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, groovy

My OCD has gotten the better of me and I'm going through my groovy codebase replacing simple strings with double quotes around them into single quoted strings.

However, I want to avoid GStrings that actually contain dollar symbols and variables.

I'm using IntelliJ to do the substitution, and the following almost works:

```
From: "([^$\"\n\r]+)"
  To: '$1'
```

It captures strings without any dollars in, but only partially skips any strings that contain them.

For example it matches the quotes between two double quoted strings in this case:

```
foo("${var}": "bar")
           ^^^^
```

Is it possible to create a regex that would skip a whole string that contained dollars, so in the above case it skips `"${var}"` and selects `"bar"`, instead of erroneously selecting `": "`?

EDIT: Here's a section of code to try against

```
table.columns.elements.each{ columnName, column ->
  def columnText = "${columnName} : ${column.dataType}"
  cols += "${columnText}\n"
  if (columnText.length() > width) {
    width = columnText.length()
  }
  height++
}
builder."node"("id": table.elementName) {
  builder."data"("key": "d0") {
    builder."y:ShapeNode"()
  }
}

def foo() {
  def string = """
a multiline quote using triple quotes with ${var} gstring vars in.
"""
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do single and triple quote replacements separately.

**Single quotes:**

Use a look ahead for an even number of quotes after your hit. A negative look behind stops it matching the inner quotes of triple quoted strings.

```
Find: (?<!")"([^"$]*)"(?=(?:(?:[^"\r\n]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
Replace: '$1'
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/ble9nK975y).

**Triple quotes:**

Use a simpler match for triple quoted strings, since they are on their own lines.

```
Find: """([^"$]*?)"""
Replace: '''$1'''
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/fO4InZik3j), which includes a triple-quoted string that contains a variable.

Comment: This is working for my test case using a web regex testing tool, but fails in IntelliJ. Particularly in the example I've added to my question, it matches the quote at the end of the second line, and continues until it matches to the first quote on line 3, offering to replace it with '    cols += '. After this point, everything is inverted, like it's 1 quote out, so from the end of line 3 down to the quote before node is the next section, and so on. This is why I had to add /r/n checking in my own regex as it was jumping over multiple lines.

Comment: Ah, it's failing in IntelliJ because elsewhere in the file I have triple quotes, which affects the search. I'll update my test case

Comment: @Mark See edited answer for (what I believe is) a workable solution.

Comment: Excellent, I hadn't noticed you were catering for dollars in triple quotes too. Answer accepted

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the first quote comes after even number of quotes:

```
^[^\n\r"]*(?:(?:"[^"\n\r]*){2})*"([^$\"\n\r]+)"
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/HYmEHD/5) you can play with it.

Explanation:

- `^[^"\n\r]*` - some non-quotes at the beginning
- `"[^"\n\r]*` - a quote, then some more non-quotes
- `(?:"[^"\n\r]*){2}` - let's have two of this
- `(?:(?:...))` - actually, let's have 0, 2, 4, 6, ... whatever amount of this
- Then your regex comes to match the right string: `"([^$\"\n\r]+)"`

If intellij supports that, then you can make it faster by replacing the non-capturing groups `(?:...)` with atomic groups `(?>...)`.

This regex finds the last string in the line so you'll have to run the replace several times.

#### Update

Updated the negated character classes with the newline characters. Now it works well for multi-line texts too. Still, you'll have to run it several times because it finds only one string per line.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I tried this against a meatier piece of code, and it didn't quite work, I've added the code snippet example that fails to my question.

Comment: I believe my updated code finds the last `"..."` string in each line. So you need to run the `'$1'` replacement several times, until it will be allright. This is the best I could come up with. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/HYmEHD/7) is the optimalized snippet with atomic groups.

Comment: Ahem, sorry... I think I know what's wrong: the replacement didn't work.
if you add a set of parentheses like this: `^([^\n\r"]*(?>(?>"[^"\n\r]*){2})*)"([^$\"\n\r]+)"`, i.e. before the desired string, then the replacement should be `$1'$2'`. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/HYmEHD/8) is the demo.

Comment: Thanks for this Tamas, learnt a few things, but I'm going to accept Bohemian's answer as it does all strings on a single line. Gave you an upvote for your efforts though :)